# Zxing barcode integeration: The constructor IntentIntegrator() is undefined

Tags: android, integration, barcode, zxing

i'm trying to integrate Zxing library, and use the barcode scanner from my app.

so, downloaded the 2 java files IntentIntegrator and IntentResult, put them into this package:

```
com.google.zxing.integration
```

where my app is in this package:

```
com.example.mindstormsgamepad
```

the code I'm using in my activity is:

```
package com.example.mindstormsgamepad;

import com.google.zxing.integration.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.IntentResult;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * BarcodeScan Activity
 */

    public class BarcodeScanActivity extends CommonActivity implements OnClickListener{ 

        /** Debug */
        protected String TAG_SUB = "BarcodeScanActivity";

        private Button scanBtn;
        private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            initTabSub( TAG_SUB );  
            log_d( "onCreate" );        
            super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
            /* set the layout on the screen */
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.activity_barcode_scan, null );
            setContentView( view ); 

            /* Initialization of Bluetooth */
            initManager( view );
            setTitleName( R.string.activity_barcodescan );
            initButtonBack();
            initInputDeviceManager();

          Toast.makeText(BarcodeScanActivity.this, "QR Scan!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            /* Initialization of Scanning */
          scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
          formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
          contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
          scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

    // --- onCreate end ---

        /**
         * === onResume ===
         */
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            log_d( "onResume()" );
            super.onResume();
            startService();
            mInputDeviceManager.register(); 
        }

        /**
         * === onPause ===
         */
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            log_d( "onPause()" );
            super.onPause();
            sendStop();
            mInputDeviceManager.unregister();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start Scan
            if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){

                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

            }
        }


            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                //retrieve scan result
                IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                if (scanningResult != null) {
                    //we have a result
                    String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                    String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                    formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                    contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);

                    }else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "No Barcode data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                }
    }
```

but I'm getting this error,
The constructor IntentIntegrator(BarcodeScanActivity) is undefined

and

The method initiateScan(Activity) in the type IntentIntegrator is not applicable for the arguments ()

on these lines:

```
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

I'm new to android programming,
how to solve this problem?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

For Result Do the code in onActivityResult method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "result ", 1000).show();
        if (requestCode == 0) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //do code here
            }

            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //do code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it did work and the scanner started to work. but the barcode data was shown in the camera only. how to send it back to the "startActivityForResult"and show it in the app itself.

Comment: Implement `onActivityResult`

Comment: This is just reimplementing IntentIntegrator less completely. It doesn't get at the root cause of the OP.

Comment: For the betterment use ZBarScannerActivity Lib in future.
Here's the link to download the lib 
https://github.com/dm77/ZBarScanner

Comment: @user3243147 Perfect. ZBarScanner worked easily. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This means your Activity does not ultimately extend android.app.Activity. see what CommonActivity extends. Otherwise maybe you somehow have an old or wrong copy of the IntentIntegrator.

Comment: thnks for reply, "IntentIntegrator" is from https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java?r=2002

Comment: The project is at GitHub.com/zxing/zxing now